# Can `Man In Middle Attack` break The CSRF_TOKEN protection?

Tags: django, web, csrf-protection, json-web-token

I am looking into the `django csrf_token` protection, I have known about how it works, but there is still a question that I want to know.For example, in a http request, if the attacker can sniffer all of a user's network traffic, which means the attacker can still get the `csrf_token` and make a fake request with the valid `csrf_token`. As mentioned `CSRF`, I have the same doubt about `JSON WEB TOKEN`, if the attacker get a user's TOKEN ,he\she can still make a fake request. Could you please explain if my example description is correct? And if so, what can we do to handle this?

Comment: You should ask this on the Security Stack Exchange site

Comment: Yes. If the man-in-the-middle can read (or even intercept) all your traffic, they can get to the authentication secrets and pretend to be you. Neither CSRF nor JWT tokens prevent that. And you handle it by using HTTPS with certificate validation (so that you can know who you are talking to).

Answer (score 2):

This is correct. The way around this is to encrypt the entire connection so it cannot be sniffed (i.e. use HTTPS). Setting that up is outside of the scope of Stack Overflow.